# If statement changing when it's not supposed to

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the formula below. The overall goal of the formula is to compare dates and tell me how far ahead or behind we are based upon the end date. Column C is for "projected dates" and column D is for "actual dates". So, use the projected until we know the actuals, then switch to the actuals once they're known.

What the formula is supposed to say (basically) is: "If D7 (actual end date) is blank, then subtract the projected dates in C4 from C7, but if D7 is not blank (i.e., filled in with an actual date), then subtract the actual dates in D4 from D7".

The problem is, as soon as you fill in a date in D***4*** (not D7, as the formula says), the cell where the formula is changes. Which I don't understand, because the formula is saying "If D7 is blank, then do this..." not "when D4 is not blank, do this..."

In other words, it shouldn't do anything until D7 is filled in, but it changes when D4 is filled in.

What am I missing?

```
=IF(D7="",((($K$14-$K$11)/(100/($C$7-$C$4)))*100)*-1,((($K$14-$K$11)/(100/($D$7-$D$4)))*100)*-1)
```

Comment: `IF(D7="","",[calculation])`

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding, but isn't your formula saying "If D7 is blank, leave this cell blank, if it's filled in, do this calculation"? What I'm trying to say is "If D7 is blank, use these dates, if it's filled in, use these dates".

Comment: For the observed behaviour, one of your cells, `C7` or `C4` presumably, must _already_ be referring to `D4` - have you checked this, i.e. that your cells are not all fully independent of each other ?

Comment: Like Spectral Instance says it's probably either `K14`, `K11`, `C7` or `C4` that have a calculation referring to `D4`.

Comment: Yes, that's it... K14 references D4... ugh... thanks so much! I've been staring at this too long!!!